# Writing a 2 player rock-paper-scissors game

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to write a function RPS.

The function takes 2 lists of symbols ('R 'P or 'S) and produces a string based on the rock paper scissors rule i.e. "player 1 wins", "player 2 wins" or "tie".

An example execution of the program would be :

(RPS (list 'R 'R 'P)(list 'R 'P 'S) -> "player 2 wins"
(RPS (list 'R 'P)(list 'S 'R 'R) -> "player 1 wins"

This is my code so far :

```
(define (RPS slst1 slst2)

  (cond

    [(and(empty? slst1)(empty? slst2)) "tie"]

    [(empty? slst2) "player 1 wins"]

    [(empty? slst1) "player 2 wins"]

    [else

      (cond

        [(and(symbol=?(first slst1) 'R)

             (symbol=?(first slst2) 'P))"player 1 wins"]

        [(and(symbol=?(first slst1) 'R)

             (symbol=?(first slst2) 'S))"player 2 wins"]

        [(and(symbol=?(first slst1) 'p)

             (symbol=?(first slst2) 'R))"player 2 wins"]

        [(and(symbol=?(first slst1) 'P)

             (symbol=?(first slst2) 'S))"player 2 wins"]

        [(and(symbol=?(first slst1) 'S)

             (symbol=?(first slst2) 'R))"player 2 wins"]

        [(and(symbol=?(first slst1) 'S)

             (symbol=?(first slst2) 'P))"player 1 wins"]

        [(and(symbol=?(first slst1) 'S)

             (symbol=?(first slst2) 'P))"player 1 wins"]

        [(and(symbol=?(first slst1) 'S)

             (symbol=?(first slst2) 'R))"player 2 wins"])]))
```

How can I make this function recursive so that it moves onto the remaining elements of the list?

Comment: Hint: You're missing one case in your `cond`...

Answer (score 1):

Make a separate function that compares one symbol vs another symbol (don't forget to take the cases into account when the 2 symbols are equal, you're not doing that at the moment) and call that function on the `car` of the symbol lists. Depending on the result of the comparison (tie, player 1 wins, player 2 wins) in your new function, you then recursively call, in case of a tie, your RPS function on the `cdr` of the original inputs or return the winning player in the other cases.

Make sure you return some sensible result from your new function e.g. 0 = tie, 1 = player 1 wins, 2 = player 2 wins.

This version of RPS will continue until a player wins 1 round or until the symbol lists are empty. However, from your question it's not entirely clear if that's what you want.

You could also `map` your new function over the 2 input lists,  this will produce a list like `'(0 0 2)` or `'(1 2 1)` etc. , showing you the results of every round. Based on these results you could derive the winner of the entire game. For extra cleverness you could return -1 if player one wins and +1 if player 2 wins, then you can just sum the result of the map -> if it's positive, player 2 has won, 0 = tie and negative means player 1 has won.

-> more info on map: http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Mapping-of-Lists.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply this function greatly. It's quite frankly some ugly code.

First `(else (cond ...))` is never good form.  It means if this conditions above aren't true, check these other conditions. It's redundant

Second that second `cond` has no `else` condition, and you haven't tested earlier in the code to make sure the input is proper. Adding a `[(not (member? (first slst1) '(R P S))) "player 2 wins"]` and a converse for `slst2` would solve that. At the very least an `(else (error ...))` will stop program execution on unexpected input.

Third You are missing a very big condition, that is the tie condition `[(symbol=? (first slst1) (first slst1)) "tie")]` Or if that isn't the behaviour you want see five.

Fourth you don't have to compare every combination. If there isn't a tie or player 1 doesn't win, you can assume player 2 wins. Or you can use an `if` statement as the second `cond` clause like so: `[(symbol=?(first slst1) 'R) (if (symbol=? (first slst2) 'P) "player 1 wins" "player 2 wins"]` Alternatively you could make a data structure that contains the rules. `(('R ('R 0) ('P -1) ('S 1)) ...)`and lookup the outcome through that.

Fifth you use some very weird logic when one list is empty and the other isn't'. Usually you stop computation and ignore the last part of the longer list, or do something special with that list. Additional your rules for winning or losing aren't clear. Does the first pairing that produces a win decide the winner, or like a best out of X where X is the length of the (shortest || longest) list? If it's based on score, you need to pass score as an explicit state and make the proper comparison when one or both of the lists are empty. If it's based on the first win as your `[(empty? slst1) "player 2 wins"]` suggests then the tie catcher in my thrird point should call `RPS` with the 'cdr`'s of`slst1`and`slst2`

Given that the behaviour you want isn't clear here are the three versions

Version for first win wins

```
(define (RPS slst1 slst2)
  (cond
    [(and(empty? slst1)(empty? slst2)) "tie"]
    [(empty? slst2) "player 1 wins"]
    [(empty? slst1) "player 2 wins"]
    [(not (member? (first slst2) '(R S P)))
     (if (member? (first slst1) '(R S P))
         "player 1 wins"
         (RPS (rest slst1) (rest slst2)))] ;tie
    [(not (member? (first slst1) '(R S P)))
     "player 2 wins"]
    [(symbol=? (first slst1) (first slst2))
     (RPS (rest slst1) (rest slst2))]
    [(symbol=? (first slst1) 'R)
     (if (symbol=? (first slst2) 'S)
         "player 1 wins"
         "player 2 wins")]
    [(symbol=?(first slst1) 'P)
     (if (symbol=?(first slst2) 'R)         
         "player 1 wins"
         "player 2 wins")]
    [(symbol=?(first slst1) 'S)
     (if (symbol=?(first slst2) 'P)         
         "player 1 wins"
         "player 2 wins")]
    [(else (error "RPS -- unexpected input " slst1 " " slst2))]))
```

Score-keeping version with rules in data structure

```
(define *RPS-Rules*
 (list
   (list 'R
         (list 'R  0)  ;;tie
         (list 'P -1)  ;;paper beats rock
         (list 'S  1)) ;;rock beats siscors
   (list 'P
         (list 'R  1)  ;;paper beats rock
         (list 'P  0)  ;;tie
         (list 'S -1)) ;;siscors beat paper
   (list 'S
         (list 'R -1)  ;;rock beats scissors
         (list 'P  1)  ;;paper beats rock
         (list 'S  0)));;tie

(define (RPS-result throw1 throw2)
  (first 
    (rest 
      (assoc throw2 
             (assoc throw1 *RPS-Rules*))))) 
 ;;returns 1,0, or -1

(define (RPS slst1 slst2)
 (RPS-helper slst1 slst2 0 )


(define (RPS-helper sl1 sl2 score)
   (cond
    [(and (empty? sl1)(empty? sl2)) 
     (cond [(> score 0) "player 1 wins"]
           [(< score 0) "player 2 wins"]
           [else "tie"])]
    [(empty? sl1) ;;if you want score based on shortest list
     (RPS-helper sl1 '() (- score (length sl2)))]
    [(empty? sl2) ;;dont do math on score here
     (RPS-helper '() sl2 (+ score (length sl1)))]
    [(not (member? (first sl1) '(R S P)))
     (if  (member? (first sl2) '(R S P))
          (RPS-helper (rest sl1) 
                      (rest sl2)
                      (- score 1))
          (RPS-helper (rest sl1) 
                      (rest sl2)
                      score))]
    [(not (member? (first sl2) '(R S P)))
     (RPS-helpter (rest sl1)
                  (rest sl2)
                  (+ score 1))]
    [Else (RPS-helper (rest sl1)
                      (rest sl2)
                      (+ score
                         (RPS-result (first sl1)
                                     (first sl2))))])
```

Comment: Given the second structure it should relatively straightforward to make a rock-paper-siscors-lizard-spock variant. Some of the `member?` logic in RPS-helper could be moved to  RPS-Result.  Additionally *RPS-Rules* could be simplified if you moved logic for detecting ties into RPS-Result. Additional simplification from dropping the -1 cases in *RPS-Rules*  instead allowing RPS-result to negate a call to itself should no winner winner be found

Comment: Thanks! your first solution: (version for win wins) is very useful. However it does not produce the results I want: I want - (RPS (list 'R 'R 'P) (list 'R 'P 'S)) -> "Player 2 wins"  yours renders "player 1 wins"  and I want-   (RPS (list 'R 'P) (list 'S 'R 'R))-> "Player 1 wins"  yours produces "player 2 wins"

Comment: Okay my rules in the first example were wrong, I had rock beating paper and scissors beating rock. Fixed now.  You still haven't' clarified if you want to go by first win (as my first example) or by score (my second) and if want forfeits to count as wins or not? What should `(RPS '(R P) '(S R R S P))` do?

Comment: I want to go by first win

Answer (score 0):

The Rock-paper-scissors-lizard-spock is a bit off topic, but I'll post as an afterthought in a separate answer to show a bit better organization of the code in the second example.

```
(define (RPS slst1 slst2)
  (compare-game slst2 slst2 *RPS-Rules*))

(define (RPSLS slst1 slst2)
  (compare-game slst2 slsts2 *RPSLK-Rules*))

(define (compare-game game slst1 slst2 rules)
  (define (helper sl1 sl2 score)
    (cond
      [(and (empty? sl1)(empty? sl2)) 
       (cond [(> score 0) "player 1 wins"]
             [(< score 0) "player 2 wins"]
             [else "tie"])]
      [(empty? sl1) 
       (helper sl1 '() (- score (length sl2)))]
      [(empty? sl2) 
       (helper '() sl2 (+ score (length sl1)))]
      [else 
       (helper (rest sl1)
               (rest sl2)
               (+ score
                  (game-result (first sl1)
                               (first sl2)
                               rules)))]))
  (helper slst1 slst2 0))
;if you want score of X to be
;based on length of shortest list
;dont do math on score after the
;[(empty?...] cond clauses


(define (game-result throw1 throw2 rules)
  (let ((assoc1 (assoc throw1 rules))
        (assoc2 (assoc throw2 rules))
        (value (lambda (assoc-elem) (if assoc-pair 
                                        (first (rest (assoc-elem)))
                                        #f))))
    (cond [(not (and assoc1 assoc2))
           (cond [(and (not assoc1) (not assoc2)) 0] 
                 [assoc1 1] 
                 [else  -1])] 
          [(symbol=? throw1 throw2) 0]
          [(value (assoc thow2 (rest assoc1)))]
          [(let ((assoc2.1 (assoc throw1 (rest assoc2))))
             (if assoc2.1 (- (value assoc2.1)) #f))]
          [else (error "compare-game-result failed with args " 
                        throw1 
                        throw2 
                        rules 
                        "Rules incomplete?")])))
 ;returns 0, +-1, +- win value from rules, or error
 ;;playing fast and lose with anything not #f is true
 ;;and one-clause cond statements
 ;;;assumes ties are 0 points
 ;;;assumes default/forfiets are worth 1 point
 ;;;Does not assume all genuine wins are 1 point

(define *RPS-Rules*
 (list
   (list 'R
         (list 'S 1)) ;;rock crushes scissors
   (list 'P
         (list 'R 1)) ;;paper covers rock
   (list 'S
         (list 'P 1)));;scissors cuts paper

(define *RPSLK-Rules*
 (list
   (list 'R
         (list 'S 1)  ;;rock crushes siscors
         (list 'L 1)) ;;rock crushes lizard
   (list 'P
         (list 'R 1)  ;;paper covers rock
         (list 'K 1)) ;;paper disproves spock
   (list 'S
         (list 'P 1)  ;;scissors cut paper
         (list 'L 1)) ;;scissors decapitate lizard 
   (list 'L
         (list 'K 1)  ;;lizard poisons spock
         (list 'P 1)) ;;lizard eats paper
   (list 'K
         (list 'S 1)  ;;spock smashes scissors
         (list 'R 1)));;spock vaporizes rock
```